# How can I read audio along with text in android

Tags: android, audio

I have a comic Audio file.When I start it  has to speak along with text means when it read first text then it will highlight that text.Can It is possible in android.

please help me

thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably used TextTSpeech engine, who I think read at the same speed all the time.. 
If it is the case you could probably make your words highlight as fast as TTS engine is going..

But not really sure.
I know it is possible because some modified android system (as MIUI) are using this thing with the media player..